# How can I make this circuit with an Arduino

Tags: arduino

Here is my Schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgMyjH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a 12 volt PSU to a 5 volt regulator to the arduino. I want to power a computer fan (12V 180mA) off the wall adapter, and controlled by an arduino LOW or HIGH signal. What part will I need for this? Is a transistor what I'm looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Search for NPN controlled fan circuit. Show more effort.

Comment: We expect people that come here for help to at least have done some kind of research. There's literally thousands of sites that can tell you how to do this. Including this site if you would use the search field.

Comment: what is that a schematic of?   .... were you too rushed to post a tidy schematic? .... you will need an arduino and a fan and a relay to turn on the fan (none of which are in the schematic)

Comment: @jsotola why do you say a relay is needed?

Answer (score 3):

Close.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNf9vO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You don't need the Voltage regulator at all ...the Arduino is rated to 12 V on Vin, and already has an on board regulator. You also don't need a catch diode on a computer 12 V DC fan, they are BLDC motors with onboard electronics.